# Does returning numpy array always produce a view?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have noticed that , say, this function,

```
def f(x):
    return(x)
```

would always return a view of the numpy array. Is this generally true? Are there any weird corner-cases I have to take into consideration, or can I rely on the fact that when an array is an argument to the *return* statement I'm always getting the view?

Comment: As a side note, there's no need for the brackets in `return(x)` - `return` is a [statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) rather than a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't always get a view.  In fact, with the function that you have defined (`f`), you'll only get a view if you pass a view into the function.  Otherwise, you'll get the original array back (which, I suppose in a lot of ways *acts* like a view)...

```
>>> def f(x):
...   return x
... 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> b = f(a)
>>> b is a
True
```

Since `b` and `a` are the same array, changes to `b` are also reflected in `a` (and vice-versa) but it isn't a view since they're the same array.

Comment: @ali_m -- I was talking about OP's identity function specifically.  I'll edit to try to make that more clear.